# Emploi de l'adjectif « pathologique » dans les mathématiques et la physique

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, adjectifs, connotation

J'essaie de rendre en français la phrase ci-dessous :

> Of special importance is the behavior of the new solutions near to the
> point of application of the loads where pathological singularities and
> discontinuities exist in the classical solutions.

Voici mon effort :

> Le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application
> des charges, où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités
> pathologiques dans les solutions classiques, est d'une importance
> particulière.

- Peut-on employer **pathologique** dans ce contexte (en français) ?
- Est-ce une connotation médicale ?
- Sinon, quel est l'adjectif pertinent (e.g., inhérent) ?

Comment: Dimitris, you should provide the provenance of sentences taken from existing texts. This is from the International Journal of Solids and Structures (which I found on ludwig.guru). This is not medical except in the sense of being very abnormal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La connotation médicale dans le texte original est tout à fait transposable en français avec une traduction littérale.

Ici, " pathological singularities " fait références à des solutions mathématiques singulières induisant des inconsistances, des contradictions, ou d'autres problèmes liés au domaine en question (de la physique appliquée?).

En français, "pathologique" transmet très bien ce sens là.

Comment: On parle souvent de 'pathological cases' pour désigner des situations intrinsèquement problématiques mais sans vraie portée: 'pathological singularities' serait alors redondant (si la singularité est intrinsèque et non le fruit du modèle). Il faudrait un peu plus de contexte.

Answer (score -2):

Selon le TLFi, il n'existe pas de trace d'un emploi de cet adjectif au sens figuré; il est assez strictement réservé <sup>1</sup> à l'usage médical. Il n'y a aucun problème en anglais; on peut lire ceci dans le dictionnaire d'Oxford :

> sense 3. *Math* Grossly abnormal in properties or behaviour, as compared with functions normally encountered in classical applications. (mid twentieth century)

Cela indique que la possibilité d'introduire un néologisme est ouverte au traducteur. Cependant, un terme voisin comme « handicapantes » pourrait sembler préférable; l'état que représente celui-ci par exemple, est caractéristique de la maladie, mais il ne faut pas insister là-dessus; c'est essentiellement ce en quoi résulte la « maladie » des fonctions : un handicap dans les manipulations théoriques. Seulement, dans l'absolu il n'est pas question de divergence de l'entité dite pathologique d'un état « sain » ; tout cela est très subjectif ; tout ce que l'on veut dire c'est que le mathématicien a un problème difficile, qui rend les applications sujettes à des impossibilités. Il n'y a pas de dérivée de *f(x)=|1-x²|* en -1 et  1 mais la fonction *f* n'est pas anormale, pas « malade » ; elle a seulement certaines particularités ou encore, singularités. Personnellement, je pense qu'un autre terme est souhaitable, un terme qui ne confère ni la pseudo anormalité, ni l'aspect peu pratique qui résulte pour le scientifique.

handicaper :  Au fig. Infliger (à quelqu'un, quelque chose) un désavantage quelconque.

<sup>1</sup><sub>(TLFi) Qui concerne les troubles, les états maladifs ou morbides liés à des phénomènes de société</sub>

ADDITION

Grace à une remarque par user **Peter Shor**, qui signale la sphère cornue d'Alexander, peut être obtenue la certitude que « pathologique » est utilisable dans le sens de l'original anglais. Voir les liens suivants, dont le premier est celui fourni par Peter Shor ;

[sphère cornue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sph%C3%A8re_cornue_d%27Alexander)

[cas pathologique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cas_pathologique)

Comment: Despite the TLFi, it's in use in mathematics. Dans [wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sph%C3%A8re_cornue_d%27Alexander), on dit que "la sphère cornue d'Alexander est un célèbre exemple de surface pathologique."

Comment: Je confirme que « pathologique » est tout autant utilisé en mathématiques en français que « *pathological* » en anglais.